# Unable to Connect ARIS Mashzone with my SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, jdbc, mashup, aris

Unable to make connection from ARIS Mashzone to SQL database

I want to connect `Aris Mashzone 2.3.1.0.1656` with `MySQL` Database. I have installed `mysql-connector-java-5.1.5.jar` and `sqljdbc4.jar` under jdbcdriver  directory.

Database URL used to connect to SQL database:

Driver: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Database URL: `jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=******)(port=*****)(User=****)/DBname`

It gives me below error while connecting to Aris Mashzone .

> "The following error occurred when connecting to database "QA_DB": Must specify at least one slave host to connect
>   to for master/slave replication load-balancing functionality"

Then I installed `sqljdbc4.jar` and placed it in jdbcdriver directory and restarted the server.

It is giving me different error .

> PFB error
>
> "The following error occurred when connecting to database "QA_DB": Communications link failure Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago."

Jar file which is placed in jdbcdrivers "sqljdbc4.jar"

Can anyone helps me out to get it set up or to provide details why this error is coming.

Regards
Parth Magu

Comment: Do you mind providing us the code and the JDBC URL being used?

Comment: The JDBC URL provided is not what you are supposed to use, look for MySQL documentation